# NHibernate and DataGridView binding

Tags: c#, nhibernate, architecture

I have my NHibernate objects binded to DataGridView using BindingSource, and what I want is to be the objects strongly connected to the database, i.e. if somthing changes in the objects the changes should be effect the database after Commit (user press Save button) or RollBack transaction otherwise (Cancel button). But there are some problems: 
1. If transaction rollbacked the objects isn't effected back.
2. How to monitor changes in the objects list. Using BindingSource events breaks my model, and it's not even possible to delete object in the database, becourse BindingSource change event invokes after list item deleted.
Guys, I realy don't know how to implement such model, if you have expirince in this scope, please, advice me something.

### class

```
    class AudienceFormController
{
    private AudiencesForm _form;
    private IList<AudienceType> _audiences;
    private BindingSource _bindingSource;

    private void BindTable()
    {
        _audiences = Controller.Manager.RetrieveAll<AudienceType>(SessionAction.Begin);

        _bindingSource = new BindingSource();
        _bindingSource.DataSource = _audiences;
        _bindingSource.AllowNew = true;

        _form.AudienceTypesDataGridView.DataSource = _bindingSource;
        _form.AudienceTypesDataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
        _form.AudienceTypesDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

        _form.SaveATypeButton.Click += new EventHandler(SaveATypeButton_Click);
        _form.CancelATypeButton.Click += new EventHandler(CancelATypeButton_Click);

        _bindingSource.ListChanged += new System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventHandler(_bindingSource_ListChanged);
    }

    void _bindingSource_ListChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.ListChangedType)
        {
            case ListChangedType.ItemChanged:
                {
                    Controller.Manager.Save(_bindingSource.List[e.NewIndex]);
                    break;
                }
            //case ListChangedType.ItemDeleted:
            //    {
            //        Controller.Manager.Save(_bindingSource.List[e.OldIndex]);
            //        break;
            //    }

        }
    }

    void CancelATypeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Controller.Manager.RollBack();
        _bindingSource.DataSource = Controller.Manager.RetrieveAll<AudienceType>(SessionAction.Begin);
    }

    void SaveATypeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {;
        Controller.Manager.Commit();
    }

    public AudienceFormController(AudiencesForm form)
    {
        _form = form;
        BindTable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how your setup looks - what are yout 'nhibernate objects'? Are we talking business objects or NH entities? Are you trying to bind directly to NH entities? Can you provide some code?

Comment: We are talking about NH entities.

Comment: Are you using Fluent or are you mapping with xml?

Comment: I added the code. I use mapping with xml.
Bu tje problem with implementation of add/insert/delete operations.